# Why shallow DL models outperform deeper models when fine-tuned on medical images?

Tags: image-processing, keras, classification

I’ve initialized VGG16 and InceptionV3 with ImageNet weights and fine-tuned from the first layer (since the medical images are different from ImageNet classes) using very small learning rate (SGD, lr=0.001) on a chest X-ray dataset of 20K images (512*512 resolution). I reportedly find the VGG-16 shows no overfitting and is more accurate than Inception-V3 that overfits and gives less accurate results. Does that make sense to fine-tune the VGG-16 from the first layer?

Comment: Does it make sense *based on what you told us*: yes. However, the number of parameters are less for Inception V3 than VGG-16, but inception v3 has been difficult than VGG-16 to train well. So go ahead with VGG-16. In my opinion, fine-tuning from first layer will give better results but if the data available is less (quantifying less is difficult without trial and error), then fine tuning after first max-pooling may be better. In short, you will have to try. It may be worth trying ResNet-18 / ResNet-34, trains faster than VGG-16 and gives better accuracy.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the useful suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a programming question.